# ANT task how to rename multiple folders under a sub folder

Tags: ant

I have folder sample which contains multiple folders and file in it like below.

```
sample/folderA/file1.csv
sample/folderA/file2.csv
sample/folderB/file1.csv
sample/folderB/file2.csv
sample/folderB/file3.csv
```

I am looking for ANT command which can rename (or copy) all the folder form folderA to folderA-bak like below.

```
 sample/folderA-bak/file1.csv
sample/folderA-bak/file2.csv
sample/folderB-bak/file1.csv
sample/folderB-bak/file2.csv
sample/folderB-bak/file3.csv
```

Note: There will be lot of folders and I do not know there name, what ever there name is I need to append -bak at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ant [copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with nested [fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) and [regexmapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html), something like:

```
<copy todir="what/ever/sample">
<fileset dir="what/ever/sample"/>
  <regexpmapper from="(.+)(folder.)(.+)" to="\1\2-bak\3"/>
</copy>
```

to make  it work regardless of the dirname use this regex:

```
<regexpmapper from="(.+)(.+)(\\.+)" to="\1\2-bak\3"/>
```